# How can I use CSS to style the Stripe inputs on a Bigcommerce cart integration?

Tags: css, stripe-payments, bigcommerce

I am using Stripe as my payment processor on BigCommerce. It works perfectly. The problem is that my site theme has a black background. When you type in your credit card info, the text is black in the Stripe inputs so you can't see it. I've tried to use CSS in both checkout.scss and optimized-checkout.scss to try and overwrite it, but since Stripe is loaded via JS and in what looks to be an iFrame, I can't figure it out.

I've added this css to both and it still doesn't work

```
input {
    color: #eee !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use JavaScript for this,

> document.getElementById("element_id").style etc...

I did not do that thing earlier, but this solution works on these types of scenarios!

Answer (score 0):

> but since Stripe is loaded via JS and in what looks to be an iFrame, I can't figure it out.

Indeed! It doesn't use the styling in your CSS, you have to specify it via Javascript by passing a style object when creating the Element:

https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-options-style

https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/

If you're not the one writing the code that interacts with stripe.js at this level you probably want to reach out to Bigcommerce or something to ask them to expose access in some way.

```js
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');
var elements = stripe.elements();

var card = elements.create('card', {
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#666EE8',
      color: 'white', // color of the text : https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style 
      lineHeight: '40px',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
      fontSize: '15px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7E0',
      },
    },
  }
});
card.mount('#card-element');
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


body {
  background: #171515;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.group {
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px 0 rgba(49,49,93,0.10),
              0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  color: #8898AA;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.group label:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F5FA;
}

label > span {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.field {
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 0;
  color: #31325F;
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: text;
}

.field::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #CFD7E0; }
.field::-moz-placeholder { color: #CFD7E0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="group">
      <label>
        <span>Card</span>
        <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```